# Trying to add a text string to Evernote from app using Evernote SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, evernote

Trying to get text from a UITextView to a note in Evernote. Evernote  SDK installed  authorised & linked ok.

For some reason the string `noteContent` just appears as  `; layer =
; contentOffset: {0, 0}>` when displayed in Evernote

```
if([[EvernoteSession sharedSession] isEvernoteInstalled]) {

    //tags
    NSMutableArray *tagNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"iCertifi",@"electrical",@"certificates", nil];

     NSString *noteContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.note.text];

    //Note
    EDAMNote* note = [[EDAMNote alloc] initWithGuid:nil title:@"Test Note - Evernote SDK" content:noteContent contentHash:nil contentLength:0 created:0 updated:0 deleted:0 active:YES updateSequenceNum:0 notebookGuid:nil tagGuids:nil resources:nil attributes:nil tagNames:tagNames];
    [[EvernoteSession sharedSession] setDelegate:self];
    [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] saveNewNoteToEvernoteApp:note withType:@"text/html"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed this

needed to set

`[[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] saveNewNoteToEvernoteApp:note withType:@"text/html"];`

to

`[[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] saveNewNoteToEvernoteApp:note withType:@"text/plain"];`